# Batch File: How to scrape a log for certain strings and then write them to another text file?

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I am relatively new to the concept of Batch programming. My preliminary focus lies in C++/C#/Java. That being said, I've been tasked with creating a batch file to perform a certain task. I would write a program to do it but for the sake of ease, it's requested I write a simple script using Batch.

In saying that, the script basically needs to parse a log (text file) for specific strings of data. Once it has that data, it needs to write it to another text file.

The log will have a ton of information that isn't useful, so I'm simply narrowing it down to an info dump. Each string will be separated by a new line in the log, and when it's written to the other text file, each string will need to be written on its own line.

I'm not asking for someone to write the script for me, just some guidance. So far, this is all I've come up with:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

runas /user:administrator

ECHO Beginning file processing...
set "source=C:\Users\me\Desktop\testLogsFolder\testLogsFile.txt"
set "target=C:\Users\me\Desktop\output.txt"
pushd "%source%"
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('find /n /i "myString" testLogsFile.txt > output.txt"')
```

From this point, I imagine I need a DO command, and I'd also need a way to search for more than one string. Ideally, I'd be looking for 3 or 4 strings in the entire log.

Additionally, these strings will happen multiple times, for example:

```
raw log data
raw log data
myString1 424
raw log data
raw log data
MyString2 Male
MyString3 True
raw log data
raw log data
My String1 239
etc
etc
```

So this would mean that it needs to parse each string and paste it, but not overwrite the previous one named the same thing (although the value of it would/could be different).

I've considered making each string a variable and then overwriting the string each time it pastes it, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this.

Again, I'm not looking for an easy answer here. I'm just extremely new to Batch programming and only understand the basics. Any input at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I managed to get it working. It's certainly not finished, as it needs more error handling as well as some new lines between the same string types (it will be parsing a big log, so some of the strings and their values will be repeated, in these instances there needs to be a way of collecting similar strings together).

This is what I ended up with, using FINDSTR:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: variables
SET logs=C:\Users\me\Desktop\testLogsFolder\testLogsFile.txt
SET stringsToLookFor=C:\Users\me\Desktop\testLogsFolder\stringsToLookFor.txt
SET dataOutput=C:\Users\me\Desktop\dataOutput.txt

IF NOT EXIST %logs% (
        ECHO Logs not found
        )  ELSE (
                FINDSTR /G:%stringsToLookFor% %logs% >> %dataOutput%
                )
PAUSE
```

Comment: If you use the `FINDSTR` command.  You can feed it a list of search strings that you can maintain in a file. The exsiting `FOR /F` command you are using is pointless because you are writing the output of the search to a file within the cmd itself.

Comment: I see. I will look into the FINDSTR command and see if I can find a way to properly implement it. Thanks.

Comment: @Squashman, I'd say the `for /F` command line just rises a syntax error... ;-)

Comment: There is no `do` command; `do`, like `in`, is a keyword required by the `for` command; and there is a superfluous opening parenthesis in front of `for` in yoir code...

Comment: I managed to get it working using the `FINDSTR` command. Edited my original post. Definitely needs more work, but the general idea is there.